# efficiently compare the dictionary values with list items

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, which I need to compare its values after iteration with a list.

this is my code:

```
mdic = json.loads(data)
mylist = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'black']
if not mdic['color_detail']:
   raise ValueError('No color_detail available')

color_registered = False
for e in mylist:
    if dic['color_detail'] == e:
           color_registered = True
if not color_registered:
   raise ValueError('Color not registered')
```

Is there a better way to write my code? (I mean a way to skip the False/True flags)

Comment: This looks fine

Comment: You could add a `break` statement after `color_registered = True`

Comment: `color_registered = dic['color_detail'] in mylist`?

Comment: @SayandipDutta  Thanks 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
color_registered = any(e == dic['color_detail'] for e in mylist)
```

Comment: Nice. thank you. I totally forgot `any`, do you think isn't slow as it's not built-in?

Comment: @ElisaFo It's a builtin function and it's certainly faster than your loop because it does short-circuit (such as if you used a `break` inside the loop).

Answer (score 1):

The second block ought to be just this:

```
if dic['color_detail'] not in mylist:
   raise ValueError('Color not registered')
```

And the first check might better also cover the non-existence in `mdic` rather than assuming it's always there:

```
if not mdic.get('color_detail'):
   raise ValueError('No color_detail available')
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to loop the dict values
eg:

```
for i,j in dict.items():
    if j in list:
        #your logic
    else:
        #your logic
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a list when you can use a set?

```py
mdic = json.loads(data)

myset = {'blue', 'green', 'red', 'black'}

if mdic['color_detail'] in myset:
    print('good selection')
else:
    print('bad selection')
```

you can use the keyword `in` with any sequence, eg lists, tuples, strings, sets. the benefit of sets is one lookup is performed, whereas in a list each item is checked in turn until the item is found. In the worst case the item is located at the end of the list and for long lists this adds up.